# Trying to replicate SUMIFS using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, sumifs

I have a dataframe that is essentially this:

[image: Location Team Asset P01 P02 P03 P04 ... England]

And I'd like an output that's like this
[image]

Where it extends until the last period.

Is anyone sure how to do this using python/pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set your `index` to be "Location" and "Asset" and use `stack` on all the Period columns which would get you the structure you are looking for.

Then it's a matter of `groupby.sum()`:

```
df_reshaped = df.set_index(['Asset','Location'])\
    .stack().reset_index()\
        .sort_values(by=['Asset','level_2'])\
            .rename(columns={'level_2':'Period',0:'Cost'})

df_reshaped.groupby(['Asset','Location','Period'],as_index=False).sum()
```

prints:

```
   Asset Location Period  Cost
0      A     Scot    P01   163
1      A     Scot    P02   131
2      A     Scot    P03   114
3      A     Scot    P04   176
4      B      Eng    P01   134
5      B      Eng    P02    74
6      B      Eng    P03   112
7      B      Eng    P04    33
8      C      Eng    P01    85
9      C      Eng    P02    90
10     C      Eng    P03    19
11     C      Eng    P04    68
12     C     Scot    P01    51
13     C     Scot    P02    95
14     C     Scot    P03    79
15     C     Scot    P04    62
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to extend this if there was an extra few columns, for example budget and staff heads for each line, and to make the output also contain the sum of these?